# Unable to Preview my Snowflake Data Tables in DBT Cloud

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I am setting up a Snowflake + DBT integration for an interview project.

I have followed a tutorial to completion on setting up DBT and Snowflake integration. At the end of the project, the instructions are

I have 3 data tables named

```
01:25:05 Running with dbt=1.7.10
01:25:05 Registered adapter: snowflake=1.7.2
01:25:05 Unable to do partial parsing because an error occurred. Switching to full reparse.
01:25:06 Encountered an error:
Field "files" of type Union[SchemaSourceFile, SourceFile] in Manifest has invalid value SchemaSourceFile(path=FilePath(searched_path='models', relative_path='sources/source.yml',
```

I tried redoing my tutorial.
I tried manually updating my model > schema lines.
I tried adding new files and folders.

Comment: You need to update table info in sources/source.yml. also without knowing your model and sorces.yml its difficult to answer